# How can I get an access to url paramaters in django rest framework permission class?

Tags: python, django, permissions, django-rest-framework, url-parameters

I have a view:

```
class DealsView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsOwnerOrCuratorOrDirectorOrNotAllowed, )

    def get(self, request, user_pk):
        ...
```

But in order to check the permissions correctly I need to pass user_pk url argument to permission:

```
class IsOwnerOrCuratorOrDirectorOrNotAllowed(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        ...
```

By default it doesn't have any arguments except self, request, and view. How can I go through it?

Comment: @ABDULNIYASPM it's not a get parameter. The url looks like /users/<user_pk>/deals/ .

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this:

```
class IsOwnerOrCuratorOrDirectorOrNotAllowed(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        user_pk = view.kwargs.get('user_pk', None)
        ...
```